# Need help finding cause of 'object cannot be nil' error message

Tags: debugging, xcode4.5, nszombies

In my iPad app, iOS 6.0, XCode 4.5, I am getting the following message when I run:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

I have looked and looked, but I don't see where it's happening. I set NSZombies on, but got nothing that was meaningful in Instruments.  Is there a tool or setting  or something that will at least tell me where this is happening?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions using the Breakpoint Navigator, it should stop and show you a stack trace when it hits the bad line.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... this is the stack trace... totally unmeaningful...

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b87012 0x1894e7e 0x1b3ab6a 0x1b3aa20 0x565f58 0x175fe 0x17514 0x1a0ea 0x1a21a 0x1bd06 0x23b3 0x7d97b7 0x7d9da7 0x7dafab 0x7ec315 0x7ed24b 0x7decf8 0x2b2bdf9 0x2b2bad0 0x1afcbf5 0x1afc962 0x1b2dbb6 0x1b2cf44 0x1b2ce1b 0x7da7da 0x7dc65c 0x22cd 0x21f5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed all the code pertaining to Magical Record, downloaded the latest version and re-installed it.. that cured the problem!
Thanks for the suggestion tho'.